# Multiple JUnit XML results on Jenkins, publish with separate graph?

Tags: android, junit, jenkins-plugins, android-testing, junit-runner

I have multiple tests running as a part of Android Jenkins build including Unit test and Functional tests. I am able to publish the test results on Jenkins successfully but I want to see seperate result graph for Unit tests and Functional Test. Jenkins JUnit publisher only shows one graph for multiple XML files. Any help?