# Jenkins junit reporting for multiple environments

Tags: testing, jenkins, junit, ant, jenkins-pipeline

I guess my question is somewhat similar to [Multiple JUnit XML results on Jenkins, publish with separate graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725740/multiple-junit-xml-results-on-jenkins-publish-with-separate-graph) but with another scope.

We need to test our software against multiple environments (e.g. windows/linux, different browsers, server environments). As far as I've seen this is a pretty common use case, but what I can't seem to find is how to have a clean report, where you can distinguish between these environments.

I tried the following simple pipeline:

```
node {
    // dummy report
    def testResultXml = '''
        <testsuite name="ComponentTests" tests="3">
            <testcase classname="foo1" name="ASuccessfulTest"/>
            <testcase classname="foo2" name="AnotherSuccessfulTest"/>
            <testcase classname="foo3" name="AFailingTest">
                <failure type="NotEnoughFoo"> details about failure </failure>
            </testcase>
        </testsuite>
    '''

    stage('test run 1'){
        writeFile file: 'test1.xml', text: testResultXml, encoding: 'UTF-8'
        junit "test1.xml"
    }
    stage('test run 2'){
        writeFile file: 'test2.xml', text: testResultXml, encoding: 'UTF-8'
        junit "test2.xml"
    }
}
```

and got a test report from Jenkins showing me the 2 failed tests. My problem is now, if only one fails I don't know which.

Our output is from a ant junit task that has the same output (except some properties) for all environments.

Even the article about declarative pipeline 1.2 shows multi-environment tests as a example:
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/ but says nothing about the presentation of the "Run Tests On Linux" and "Run Tests On Windows" results.

Did I miss something or is there a plugin that can publish the missing information (simply having the directory of the read junit xml file would help)?

Answer (score 1):

After some testing the issue seems to be fixed already in version 1.22 of the Jenkins JUnit plugin.

The related issues where:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27395
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37598